# Nonportable Pointer Conversion

Tags: c, scanf, turbo-c

I wrote the code and compiled it with Turbo C. But it always got the "Nonportable Pointer Conversion" error. Any ideas?

```
#include "stdio.h", "conio.h"

void main(){
    char gender;
    clrscr();
    printf("Please enter your gender (M/F): ");
    scanf("&s", gender);
    if(gender == "M"){
        printf("Male");
    } else if(gender == "F"){
        printf("Female");
    } else {
        printf("Unknown");
    }
getch();
}
```

PS: I'd like to force user to enter only one alphabet (M/F), anybody knows how to do that?

Comment: #include "stdio.h", "conio.h" really?

Comment: `force user to enter only one alphabet` and how you suggest to achieve that, other than the proposed way?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you to get a better compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem <del>is</del> **are** with

*Point 1:*

```
if(gender == "M")
```

it should be

```
if(gender == 'M')
```

Reason: `"M"` represents a string, `'M'` represents a `char`.

*Point 2:*

```
scanf("&s", gender);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c", &gender);
```

Reason: Need to use proper signature of `scanf()`. `%c` is the format specifier for scanning a `char` input. You need to supply the *address of* the variable where to store the scanned value.

*Point 3:*

You've to use like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
.
.   //so on
```

Reason: If you're writing a `C` program, you have to follow `C` standards. :-)

Answer (score 0):

And adding to above solution declaring header file in double quotes means look at local directory though it works but by convention you should put std files in angular brackets.